# Nhibernate Linq query to QueryOver

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, queryover

I have the following piece of code:

```
1: ids = GetAnArrayOfIds();

2: jobEntities = jobEntities.Where(j => j.Locations.Select(l => l.Id).Any(ids.Contains));
```

How do I write 2 using QueryOver ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var results = session.QueryOver<Job>()
    .JoinQueryOver<Location>(u => u.Locations)
    .Where(loc => loc.Id.IsIn(ids))
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
    .List();
```

Hope this helps