# Nhibernate select query with subquery?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, hql

I am new to Nhibernate with C#.

Here is my SQL query:

```
select * from advis_productattributes where ID in 
(select attributeid from advis_productattributes_products where productid=1);
```

I know about simple select query in HQL:

```
string hql = @"select p from ProductAttributes_Products p.ProductId :id"; 
var query = new SimpleQuery<ProductAttributes_Products>(hql); 
query.SetParameter("id", ProductId); 
return query.Execute();
```

I have searched on net but remained failure. How do I write HQL with a subquery?

Here is design of classes.
[image]

Comment: Could you show related model classes?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi I have updated question with diagrame.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can accomplish this by using NHibernate LINQ. Please refer these Stack overflow [Answer #1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6999035/585408)
and [Answer #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51400/585408)

Comment: Thanks @Aravinth Kannan, I am sorry I am fist day with NHibarnate. Is Nhibarnate Linq Linq for Nhibarnate ? Will I need some other classes/ controls to use it ? thanks

Comment: Hi, you don't need any additional controls to use Linq for NHibernate. It all bundled with you NHibernate library. You can refer this [Tutorial](http://www.d80.co.uk/post/2011/02/20/Linq-to-NHibernate-Tutorial.aspx) to start with..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly where on the net you searched... but the official docs have all you need to know about [subqueries](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryhql-subqueries) in HQL

It's pretty much the same as SQL.